# How can I position the correlation in my scatter plot in a better way using the stat_cor function in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation, scatter-plot

I have a scatter plot in ggplot and I would like to add the correlation coefficient.

This is my code:

```
ggplot(bcflow, aes(x = age, y = vpa_baseline_mean, color = group)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "Age", y = "VPA Baseline Mean", color = "Group") +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("hc" = "#b388eb", "bc" = "#E25C6F"), 
    labels = c("BCS", "HC", "GROUP3")) + 
  ggtitle("VPA Baseline Mean by Age divided by Group") + 
  stat_cor(method = "pearson")
```

I would like to position the correlation in a way that it doesn't overlap with the dots from the scatterplot. Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot!